# Proof showing when Dijkstra’s algorithm fails for negative edge weights

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dijkstras-algorithm

How do I show the correctness proof of Dijkstra’s algorithm for negative edge weight
$\textbf{indicating the point in the proof where it breaks or does not hold}?$

I tried proving it like this, but i know that i'm not correct.

1. Set $d[s] = 0$ (where $s$ is our source).
2. Set $d[v] = \infty$ for all $v \ne s$,$v \in V$.
3. Run some sequence of UPDATE$(u,v)$ procedures on the edges of $E$.

Let $SP(s,v)$ denote the length of the shortest path from $s$ to vertex $v$. If we execute steps 1, 2, and 3, then $d[v] \ge SP(s,v)$ at the end of the process (no matter what sequence we specify in step 3).

To argue why this claim is true, we will use a very similar strategy we used in the proof of correctness: Assume, for sake of contradiction, that $f$ is the first vertex to violate this property, i.e., at some point during the procedure $d[f] < SP(s, f)$. Thus, there must have been some vertex $u$ such that we called UPDATE$(u, f)$, which resulted in $d[u] + w(u, f)$ being stored at $d[f]$ so that now $d[f] < SP(s, f)$. But $f$ is the first violator of this property, and so it must be the case that $d[u] \ge SP(s,u)$ when this update is called. Combining these observations it follows that

$$d[f] = d[u]+ w(u,v) \quad \text{(since u caused the violating update)}$$

$$\ge SP(s,u)+ w(u, f) \quad \text{(since f is the first violator;}\quad d[u] \ge SP(s,u))$$

$$\ge SP(s, f).$$

To see why the last inequality is true, note that the shortest path from $s$ to $f$ has to travel through one of $f’s$ neighboring vertices (i.e., any vertex $v$ such that $(v, f) \in E)$. $u$ is a candidate for this vertex, and if it is the case that we travel through $u$ on the shortest path from $s$ to $f$, then the length of this path is exactly $SP(s,u)+ w(u, f)$. The only other case would be if there is some better path that uses a vertex other than $u$, but in this case we have that $SP(s, f) < SP(s,u)+w(u, f)$, which proves the inequality.

Thus the last inequality show that $d[f] \ge SP(s, f)$, which contradicts the conditions we put on $f$ and therefore establishes our claim.

Comment: You write $d[f] = d[u] + w(u, v)$. What is $v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct (modulo the typo I mentionned in the comment).

Why is that not a problem about Dijkstra's correctness for negative weights? Because what you proved is $d[f] \geqslant SP(s, f)$, not $d[f] = SP(s, f)$.

It is the inequality $SP(s, f)\geqslant d[f]$ at the end of the algorithm that fails with negative weights.

Answer (score 0):

With the idea, I approached it as thus:
An example below is used to show why Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't work in this case. The figure describes a directed graph that shows why Dijkstra’s algorithm does not work when the graph contains negative edges.

[image]

$\textbf{N.B:}$ The shaded vertices represent vertices that have been removed (dequeued) from the heap.\
In the proof of Dijkstra’s algorithm, the key property is that when a vertex $v$ is dequeued from the heap, its $d[v]$ value correctly stores the length of the shortest path from $s$ to $v$. Observe that in this example given in the graph, both $u$ and $w$ are violating this property, because both of these vertices have been removed from the heap, but we can attain shorter paths for both vertices by first travelling to $v$ and then taking the negative edge $(v,u)$. Even if we updated $d[u]$ to now be $1$ after dequeuing $v$ and calling UPDATE, $d[w]$ would still be incorrect.

$\textbf{Proof of failure with negative weights:}$
From lecture note 17 - "$\emph{Graph Algorithms}$", we could see that since both $y$ and $u$ were in $S$ when $u$ was chosen, so $f[u] \le f[y]$.

The two inequalities $f(u) > d(s, u) \ge d(s, y)$ became equalities, $f[y] = d(s,y) = d(s,u) = f[u]$; So $f[u] = d(s,u)$ contradicts our hypothesis. Thus when each $u$ was inserted, $f[u] = d(s,u)$.

Hence the inequality $f(u) > d(s, u) \ge d(s, y)$ fails if there is a negative weight because with negative weight introduced to the graph, $d(s, u)$ will not always be greater than $d(s, y)$, so Dijkstra’s algorithm fails here. Based on the proof by contradiction, there must be at least one more edge in the path after $y$, and the shortest path from $s$ to $y$ must be strictly smaller than the shortest path from $s$ to $u$. But with negative edge weight, this fails. So the inequality makes this contradiction invalid.  QED

[Image Credit: ece.mcmaster.ca]